# Find the biggest most frequent number of an array

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm given an array of numbers, and am supposed to return the biggest most frequent of the numbers.

For example, if the array is [4, 1, 4, 3, 2], then I need to return 4; and if the array is [3, 3, 3], then I need to return 3.

I have a working solution:

```
(Counter(arr).most_common(1)[0][0])
```

but I'd like to solve this without using any libraries.

Comment: Can you please indicate the approaches you have tried without using libraries?

Comment: what do you mean by largest and most common? which is most important?

like provide desired output for [6,4,4,4,2,2,1] for instance. If you just want the largest, why not just `max`?

Comment: @ted for [6,4,4,4,2,2,1] you 'll get 4

Comment: so you mean it is the most common, and if several have this count, the largest of them?

Comment: @ted yes, you are right

Comment: `(Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][0])` (though incorrect) _is_ a traditional Python solution (no libraries). `Counter` is part of the core Python distribution. If you want to see how it works, [use the source, Luke](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L489).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ construct a count dict:

```
a = [6,4,4,4,2,2,1]
d = {}
for i in a:
    d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
```

2/ find largest keys:

```
largest = [key for m in [max(d.values())] for key, val in d.items() if val == m]
```

3/ get the largest:

```
result = max(largest)
```

4/ libraries and/or standard modules will be better (faster and more robust) but you asked for plain python

Comment: Or use  `sorted(d.items(),key=lambda k:k[1],reverse=True)` to obtain a sorted result base on values.

Comment: @HenryYik I wouldn't use a `sorted`, that makes the complexity `O(n log(n))` when you can pretty reasonably solve this in `O(n)`. Just use `max`, ie `max(d, key=d.get)`

Comment: Sorting is O(nlogn) right, you can obtain the max key in O(n) in a single pass (which max does internally)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `Counter` you can use a standard dictionary to emulate it's functionality, i.e. something like this by using the default value of the [dict.**get**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
from typing import List


def get_most_common(nums: List[int]) -> int:
    counts = {}
    for num in nums:
        counts[num] = counts.get(num, 0) + 1
    most_frequent_num, most_frequent_count = None, 0
    for key, value in counts.items():
        if value > most_frequent_count:
            most_frequent_num, most_frequent_count = key, value
    return most_frequent_num


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fin = open('in.txt', 'r')
    fout = open('out.txt', 'w')
    _, nums = fin.read().splitlines()
    nums = list(map(int, nums.split()))
    fout.write(str(get_most_common(nums)))
    fout.close()
```

**out.txt:**

```
4
```

with **in.txt**:

```
5
4 1 4 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use a trick.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 2]

myset = set(mylist) # equals to (1,2,4,5,7)
count = 0
element = None

for i in myset:
    if mylist.count(i) > count:
        count = mylist.count(i)
        element = i

print(element)
```

A `set` is a "list" of non repeated values, so when you do `set(list)`, this returns a set of all elements in list. Read about `set` class for more details.

EDIT:
if you are sure that all elements in your list are numeric, you can choose the biggest like this:

```
...
for i in myset:
    if mylist.count(i) > count:
        count = mylist.count(i)
        if element == None: element = i
        else: element = max(element,i)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a frequency map using a `defaultdict` and then use `max` by providing `key` as the input array `get` method.

```
def most_frequent(array):
    frequencies = defaultdict(int)
    for value in array:
        frequencies[value] += 1
    return max(frequencies, key=frequencies.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def largest_most_commmon(arr):
    # construct a dict of values and their counts
    d = {x:sum(arr==x) for x in set(arr)}
    highest_count = max(d.values())
    # filter the dict on all items with the highest count
    most_common = [item for item,count in d.items() if count==highest_count]
    return max(most_common)

np.random.seed(40)
a = np.random.randint(10,20,10)
# a = array([16, 17, 15, 18, 18, 12, 11, 17, 12, 13])

largest_most_commmon(a)
# 18
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by two for loops in o(n^2) time complexity

```
max_count=0
for i in xrange(0, len(arr)):
    item = arr[i]
    item_count = 0
    for j in xrange(0, len(arr)):
        if item == arr[j]:
            item_count += 1
    max_count = max(max_count, item_count)
print(max_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

For an in-place solution:

- sort the list increasingly,
- scan the list and count the element multiplicities,
- keep the largest multiplicity so far (in case of ties, make sure to update to the new element).

E.g.

```
1,2,3,4,4,5,4,1,5,3,1

1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5

    3 1   2     3   2
```

The largest multiplicity is `3`, seen for the last time with the value `4`.